# Linq CSV Import with line-numers (index)

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have to import a CSV file. Since the line-order is important to the data, I need it as part of the import (index).
What I do now (workaround) is the following:

```
        string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(soureFilePath, Encoding.Default);    
        //Add Line-Index
        for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
        {
            allLines[i] = i + ";" + allLines[i];
        }

        _sourceList = (from line in allLines.Skip(1)
                       let data = line.Split(new[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                       select
                           new MappingSource
                               {
                                   Index = Convert.ToInt32(data[0]),
                                   TargetEntity = data[1].Trim(),
                                   TargetFolder = data[2].Trim(),
                                   TargetLevel = data[3].Replace(',', '.').Trim(),
                                   FolderDefinition = data[4].Trim(),
                                   Type = data[5].Trim(),
                                   SourceFolder = data[6].Trim(),
                                   SourceLevel = data[7].Replace(',', '.').Trim(),
                                   BucketStructure = data[8].Trim()
                               }).ToList();
```

I find this not to be very elegant. Is there a way to get the Index right in the Linq-Statement?

Thanx

Comment: Does it have to be LINQ query syntax? Or could it also be method syntax?

Comment: Either way is fine. Tim already answered it with method syntax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "inject" the index with method syntax only:

```
_sourceList = allLines.Skip(1)
              .Select((line, index) => new{ data = line.Split(new[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.None), line, index})
              .Select(x => new MappingSource{ Index = x.index, TargetEntity = x.data[0].Trim(), ...)
              .ToList()
```

[`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869.aspx) and `Where` have appropriate overloads.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an array, this would actually work. But be vary of ever switching the underlying implementation (ie I would not recommend it).

```
var i = 0;
_sourceList = (from line in allLines.Skip(1)
                   let data = line.Split(new[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                   select
                       new MappingSource
                           {
                               Index = i++,
                               TargetEntity = data[0].Trim(),
                               TargetFolder = data[1].Trim(),
                               TargetLevel = data[2].Replace(',', '.').Trim(),
                               FolderDefinition = data[3].Trim(),
                               Type = data[4].Trim(),
                               SourceFolder = data[5].Trim(),
                               SourceLevel = data[6].Replace(',', '.').Trim(),
                               BucketStructure = data[7].Trim()
                           }).ToList();
```

Another way would be to use the second IEnumerable.Select() which gives element and index, but that one is not possible in LINQ query format.